# Is there a way to get more information from scalac when it is throwing an error?

Tags: scala

At the very least, I'd love to see the specific file that is throwing the error. I'm running into this error:

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3854

And I am fixed on scala 2.9.3, so I need to see if I can work around it.

My current flags are "-g:vars -verbose -deprecation -unchecked -encoding UTF-8", and I'm looking here http://www.scala-lang.org/old/sites/default/files/linuxsoft_archives/docu/files/tools/scalac.html and can't seem to find an option to get more information on error.

Any suggestions for how to debug something like this?

Comment: The issue you referenced is related to eclipse, is that where you are seeing the problem?  If so, what happens when you compile with scalac or sbt?

Comment: In my case, I'm getting the error from the command line. It's true that this issue was happening in eclipse, but the issue is with the type checker, not with eclipse or whathaveyou (as far as I can tell). In my specific case, our build tool is invoking the scala compiler by building the appropriate java command.

Comment: Oh, ok.  I doubt you can get the information you are looking for, since the exception is occurring in the compiler itself.